# convert byte[] to string with charset Encoding in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows phone 8 Dev and C#. I try to get String from remote server. This is my code:

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var response = await client.GetAsync(MyUrl);
  string charset = GetCharset(response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
  Debug.WriteLine("charset: " + charset); \\debug show: charset: ISO-8859-1
  var bytesCharset = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
  Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesCharset,0,bytesCharset.Length)); 
  //Debug show: `m\u1EF9 t�m`
```

`m\u1EF9 t�m` is what I got, but I expect it's Vietnamese: `Mỹ Tâm`. Can anyone give me an idea to get expected result? (I think the bytes is encoded in IOS-8859-1).

Answer (score 2):

Encoding.UTF8 should be interpreting your data correctly, as ISO-8859-1 is a subset of UTF-8. However, so that other encodings are handled transparently, it is probably better to use [HttpContent's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) [ReadAsStringAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx) method instead of ReadAsByteArrayAsync().

I suspect you have the correct string there but your debug window simply cannot display those two unicode characters properly.

Comment: I used `ReadAsStringAsync()` in real device, but I show the same results as debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static `GetEncoding` method to request a specificy codepage.
e.g.:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. After using Json.Net to parse json from remote server, my problem's gone, and I can get expected result:

```
 JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(isoText);
 String exptectedText= jArray[1].ToString();
```

Actually, I dont know why my code works :( Thank you anyway!